# Russian Roulette probability question

Tags: probability, word-problem

You are playing a game of Russian Roulette. If instead of one bullet, two bullets are randomly put in the chamber. Your opponent played the first and he was alive after the first trigger pull. You then spin the barrel. What is the probability that you loose in this round?

Comment: Is the revolver spun each round? How many bullets does this revolver take (is it a six-shooter, etc)?

Comment: @Axoren Yes, the revolver is spun each round and it is a six-shooter.

Comment: There is the practical issue of how well oiled the revolver is in relation to how the bullets are distributed in the chambers.

Comment: Then is there something else fancy going on? Otherwise it's just a ratio of $\frac{\text{# of chances for a specific event}}{\text{total # of outcomes}}$. You have two chances to get shot out of six possible events (each chamber is an event). Since it's spun every round, past events don't affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 slots: 2 with bullets and the rest are empty. What is probability you'll get one with bullet?

Answer (score 0):

There remain $4$ empty chambers and $2$ with bullets. Probability that you die is $\frac{1}{3}$.