# Russian Roulette consecutive bullets

Tags: probability

You are playing a game of Russian Roulette. If instead of one bullet, two bullets are randomly put in the chamber. Your opponent played the first and he was alive after the first trigger pull. You don't spin the barrel. What is the probability that you loose in this round?

I looked at the solution for the above question and that for when there are bullets in two consecutive positions, with everything else the same, and can't tell why there would be a difference in survival given that you don't spin in both cases.

My issue is, I would have thought the chance of survival in both cases would be $3/4$ as the chance of survival of the opponent would be $1/4$, but for the first question, the book I'm looking at conditions the survival on the opponent surviving, which gives $3/5$.

Comment: This is the type of problem that is best checked empirically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Russian Roulette probability question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415865/russian-roulette-probability-question)
(same user who posted, same question exactly)

Comment: @jameselmore: Not a duplicate: this one involves two different situations.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, got it

Comment: @jameselmore These are pretty different questions. I don't even understand why this question got a vote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number the cylinders $1$ through $6$ in cyclic order, and imagine that the bullets are in cylinders $1$ and $2$. Your opponent wasn’t killed, so he must have been at cylinder $3,4,5$, or $6$. That means that if you don’t spin, you’ll be at cylinder $4,5,6$, or $1$. The four possibilities are equally likely, and exactly one of them has a bullet, so your chance of survival is $\frac34$.

Now suppose that the bullets were loaded randomly. After your opponent survives, the bullets are equally likely to be in any pair of the $5$ cylinders that he didn’t try to fire. There are $\binom52=10$ pairs, $4$ of which have a bullet in the cylinder currently under the hammer. Thus, your chance of surviving is $\frac6{10}=\frac35$.